# Issue with ui-view not rendering template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm still pretty new to using Angular's ui-router for SPAs, and I'm having some issues with the template not being rendered on the browser (I'm using Firefox).  Below is my code for app.js,

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        // route for the home page
        .state('app', {
            url:'/',
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl : 'views/header.html'
                }
            }
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

})
```

And here is my HTML,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Will this work?</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootswatch-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div ui‐view="header"></div>
</body>

<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script> 
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

Also going to provide the code for header.html,

```
<header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I receive no error messages in the web console, just an empty screen.

Comment: You should make a plunker out of this.

Comment: @rakemen https://plnkr.co/edit/mLNxL9uBa2osqnvUn8oY?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to replicate your code in one of my plunks and surprisingly it worked. I removed some of the stylesheet thingy's, intention was to make the code work. I suspect there is something wrong with the scripts you import (bower_components). I used plunkr's external libraries tool to import scripts, apart from that, rest of the code is same as yours.

Some problems with your code:

1. Put your import scripts inside the body tag and not outside.
2. In the plunk you posted in comments, you've imported Angular2 and not AngularJS.

**script.js:**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url:'/',
            views: {
                'header': {
                    templateUrl : 'header.html'
                }
            }
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
```

Check this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/oK1UE5) out.